# Phonegap Android with Flash

Tags: android, cordova, flash

just a small question

is it possible to embed swf (shockwave flash) file into webView ??
am developing an android application using phonegap , and like you know phonegap uses webview
so is it possible or not ??
i searched a lot , and tried the following and unfortunately nothing worked
Thanks in advance.

here is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.init();
    super.appView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am looking also for to run swf inside cordova or phonegap project.

similar thread is running here
[Flash object not showing in phonegap android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080283/flash-object-not-showing-in-phonegap-android)