# Flash object not showing in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova

i have create a application in phone gap android,i have a one screen that i want to show one static flash obj so i have put below code in my screen HTML page.

```
<object width="340" height="27" id="_fms" name="_fms" data="http://player.netromedia.com/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.16.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
   <param name="movie" value="http://player.netromedia.com/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.16.swf" />
   <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
   <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
   <param name="flashvars" value='config={
  "key":"#@ e334c866df3eabb2176",
   "clip":{
      " autoPlay":true,
      "autoBuffering":true,
      "live":true,
      "debug":true,
      "scaling":"",
      "url":"Biafra002",
      "wmode":" transparent",
      "provider":"netromedia",
      "metaData":false
   },
   "plugins":{
      "log":{
         "level":"debug",
         "filter":"org. flowplayer.*"
      },
      "content":{
         "url":"flowplayer.content-3.2. 8.swf",
         "bottom":25,
         "height":40,
         "backgroundColor":" transparent",
         "backgroundGradient":"none",
         " border":0,
         "textDecoration":"outline",
         "style":{
            "body":{
               " fontSize":14,
               "fontFamily":"Arial",
               "textAlign":"center",
               " color":"#ffffff"
            }
         }
      },
      "controls":{
         "autoHide":false,
         " fullscreen":false
      },
      "netromedia":{
         "url":"flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf",
         "netConnectionUrl":"rtmp://165. obj.netromedia.net/Biafra002"
      }
   },
   "playlist":[
      {
         "autoPlay":true,
         "autoBuffering":true,
         "live":true,
         "debug":true,
         " scaling":"",
         "url":"Biafra002",
         "wmode":"transparent",
         " provider":"netromedia",
         "metaData":false
      }
   ]
}' />
</object>
```

Comment: mobile web browser not support flash so i think your flash not support. Or you can use Some flash plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is not supported on Android devices after Android 4.1, so you will probably need to use an HTML5 video instead.

If you are testing on previous versions of Android and you know that Flash works on them, then my guess is that you need to add those URLs to your whitelist.

Comment: i know flash is not supported... so now so do u know how to use html5 to show above flash object ...

Comment: I am not aware of any way to turn the flash object into an html5 video. There might be some tools online - try searching for "convert flash to html5" or something like that. You will have to change the underlying object though and create an HTML5 video, you can't just use HTML5 video tag to play flash.